# Is there any need to check if a command already exists in a Xamarin view model?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have seen two different variation on creating a command in a ViewModel. These are listed below:

```
public partial class PhrasesFrameViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ICommand wordGridCmd;
    public ICommand WordGridCmd => wordGridCmd ?? (wordGridCmd = new Command(() =>
    {
        if (!App.pauseCard)
            if (phrasesFrame.timer1Seconds > 0)
                phrasesFrame.CancelTimer1();
            else
                phrasesFrame.CancelTimer2();
     }));
}
```

and

```
public partial class PhrasesFrameViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ICommand WordGridCmd { get; private set; }
    WordGridCmd = new Command(() =>
    {
        if (!App.pauseCard)
            if (phrasesFrame.timer1Seconds > 0)
                phrasesFrame.CancelTimer1();
            else
                phrasesFrame.CancelTimer2();
     }));
}
```

Can someone tell me is there any reason for me to do the `??` check to see if the command already exists or is it more common to go with the second way of defining the command?

Comment: Checking if it exists provides two things: 1) It is basically a "lazy" initialized property, i.e. it is not created on during the `.ctor` of the VM object and only the first first it is consumed 2) If nothing ever consumes it, it is never created. Whether or not this is appropriate for your code base is your decision.

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to check if the property (in your case it is WordGridCmd) is assigned a value or not before assigning a new value. This property will get initialized when your viewmodel is instantiated, it will not be getting initialized every time the property is accessed.